# laravel how to return a blade templating format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
function test(){
return "{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'nerds/$id', 'class' => 'pull-right')) }}
                            {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                            {{ Form::submit('Delete this Nerd', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}";
}
```

I have try above code but not working, have you ever experienced this before? thank you

Comment: do you want to make it reusable for another view?

Comment: Yes sir, in above code, the 'nerds' and id is just for an example, I want to use this function later on my view

Comment: I just update my answer, so you can use it inside function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you could:

create a new blade, called form-nerd.blade.php

`@include('form-nerd')`  where you want to use the template

you can also pass vaiables to the template, `@include('form-nerd', array('foo' => $bar))`

or put the new blade in a subdirectory called forms `forms/nerd.blade.php`

and use it like this `@include('forms.nerd')`

Comment: I know how to do it with this way, what I want to do is I want to put it on the function, but thanks anyway

Comment: if it is only because of the $id, I see no reason to make it a function, since you pass variables to a template, and include the template in a loop of nerds.

Comment: @mininoz - don't forget doublequote for variables :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reuse the form in another view or make the view more readable you could use Sub-view. For more information you can find it here [Blade Template](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) in Including Sub-Views session

**Update**
if you really want to use it inside function, try this one.

```
function test($id) { 
     return Form::open(array('url' => 'nerds/$id', 'class' => 'pull-right')) .
              Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') .
              Form::submit('Delete this Nerd', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) .
            Form::close() ; 
}
```